# dynamically Change the vertical tab LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

How to change vertical tab dynamically in LWC

**Html**

```
<div class="slds-vertical-tabs">
    <ul class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item slds-is-active" title="Tab 1" role="presentation">
            <a class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick={saveMethod}  role="tab" tabindex="0"
                aria-selected="true" aria-controls="slds-vertical-tabs-0" id="slds-vertical-tabs-0__nav">
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon"></span>
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Tab 1">Tab 1</span>
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__right-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item" title="Tab 2" role="presentation">
            <a class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick={saveMethod} role="tab" tabindex="-1"
                aria-selected="false" aria-controls="slds-vertical-tabs-1" id="slds-vertical-tabs-1__nav">
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon"></span>
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Tab 2">Tab 2</span>
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__right-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-vertical-tabs__nav-item" title="Tab 3 has a really long label and can wrap or truncate"
            role="presentation">
            <a class="slds-vertical-tabs__link" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick={saveMethod} role="tab" tabindex="-1"
                aria-selected="false" aria-controls="slds-vertical-tabs-2" id="slds-vertical-tabs-2__nav">
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__left-icon"></span>
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Tab 3 has a really long label and can wrap or truncate">Tab 3  </span>
                <span class="slds-vertical-tabs__right-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slds-vertical-tabs__content slds-show" id="slds-vertical-tabs-0" role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="slds-vertical-tabs-0__nav">
        <div class="slds-text-longform">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Tab Title</h3>
            <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-vertical-tabs__content slds-hide" id="slds-vertical-tabs-1" role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="slds-vertical-tabs-1__nav">
        <div class="slds-text-longform">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Tab Title</h3>
            <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-vertical-tabs__content slds-hide" id="slds-vertical-tabs-2" role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="slds-vertical-tabs-2__nav">
        <div class="slds-text-longform">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Tab Title</h3>
            <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
    /* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-document-query */
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    export default class Enrollment extends LightningElement {

    saveMethod(event) {
        //document.getElementsByName("slds-vertical-tabs-1");
        console.log("event target===>>"+event.target.id);
        //console.log("current target===>>"+ event.currentTarget);

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example of vertical variant if you dont want custom

Comment: and also there is no mention of tabs in your code

Comment: @User6670 Edited, Also am trying to achieve the tabs in Html code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 saveMethod(event) {
     this.template.querySelector('.slds-show').classList.add('slds-hide');
     this.template.querySelector('.slds-show').classList.remove('slds-show');
     this.template.querySelector('.slds-is-active').classList.remove('slds-is-active');

     var y = event.target.parentElement;

     y.classList.add('slds-is-active');

     var x = event.target.id;

     let target = this.template.querySelector(`[aria-labelledby="${x}"]`);

     target.classList.remove('slds-hide');
     target.classList.add('slds-show');
 }
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ycqTBcTN/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the Code, But is there any way we can simplify the .js code. Like document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";